# How do I remove a PPA?

Tags: ppa, package-management

I've added multiple third party PPAs and there are bunch of PPAs which I don't need any more. Is there simple way to remove a PPA?

Comment: Y PPA manager worked for me, thankyou

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are multiple ways to remove a PPA.

**Option 1 :**

Open the Applications menu ( <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> ) and search for `Software and Updates`

In the Software and Updates app, select the `Other Software` tab and select the desired PPA from the list. Click `Remove` to remove it.

[image: software and update]

**Option 2:**

In Terminal, use the `-r` or `--remove` flag to remove, similar to how the PPA was added. `-r` flag will only remove the said PPA. It will not revert any packages.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:repository-name/ppa
```

**Option 3:**

PPAs are stored inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. To list all the installed PPAs:

```
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

Note the name of PPA you want to remove (e.g.`google-chrome.list`), and remove it in Terminal using:

```
sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

**Option 4:**

In Terminal, use `ppa-purge`. It automatically downgrades any packages supplied by the PPA, and then removes the PPA.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:repository-name/ppa
```

Comment: I think more needs to be added here about how PPA-Purge is the only option that will correctly downgrade packages.

Comment: @LewisGoddard Thanks for the suggestion. I have added some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `y-ppa manager`

To install open terminal and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

It is GUI tool to remove, purge etc. PPA. It is also used to remove duplicate PPAs and to import missing gpg keys etc.,

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]