# elementary tweaks will not Install

Tags: release-freya

I'm trying to install elementary tweaks and ran into a problem in my Terminal. I input the following lines in my terminal...

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:versable/elementary-update
sudo apt-get update
```

But when I use that last one for *update* I get the following message at the end of my terminal...

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Full terminal output:

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

That PPA is no longer being updated (it was pre-freya). The current one is the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

*Note: Not all of the features are functional as of yet.*

Comment: Oh thank you!! One more question. How do I remove the old repository from my system?

Comment: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/372/227

Comment: This is not really true either: "AS OF FEBUARY 2015, THIS PROJECT IS NO LONGER MAINTAINED. If you are willing to put the work in, please pick the project up!" https://launchpad.net/elementary-tweaks a more up-to-date project can be found on GitHub https://github.com/I-hate-farms/elementary-tweaks