# Freya menu bar (Wingpanel) is missing

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel

I am using elementary OS Freya and the wingpanel is missing. Only the dock is showing. No other option for application, shutdown, volume control, is displayed. The whole wingpanel is missing. Please help me to resolve this issue. I do not want to reinstall the OS.

Comment: have you tried rebooting, you can do that by running `reboot` from terminal.

Comment: please let me know whether your problem solved or not.

Comment: Try to start wingpanel in terminal and past the output of the terminal here, please.

Comment: What people are neglecting to say is that the Terminal can be opened with the Windows key and T.

Comment: How do you open the terminal if you don't have the bar at the top?

Comment: @Nick As I just said, Super (Windows Key) + T should open the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet
sudo apt-get install indicator-application
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
```

Restart.

If that not working,

Make sure the `/etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-[name].desktop` file contains

```
OnlyShowIn=Unity;XFCE;GNOME;Pantheon;
```

For example,Open terminal and run:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-datetime.desktop
```

Then output should be like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Indicator Date & Time
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service
OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;
NoDisplay=true
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
AutostartCondition=GNOME3 unless-session gnome
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=indicator-datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

even I had the problem mentioned above. However the solution mentioned above did not work for me.

This answer, however, did solve the issue : 
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2988/5253

To quote :

> If you have, by any chance, tried to install [Synapse /
>   indicator-search](https://code.launchpad.net/~elementary-apps/synapse-project/indicator-search) then this could be the reason as some versions are
>   known to break WingPanel.
>
> You should be able to uninstall it by typing (in Terminal):
>
> sudo apt-get remove indicator-synapse
>
> Restart and check if it has any effect.
>
> If yes and you added a PPA just for this, you should also [remove the
>   PPA](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-do-i-remove-a-ppa).