# Top menu bar (WingPanel) is missing after reboot

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel

After installing elementary OS the system ran fine at first, but after I restarted my computer today the top menu bar called [WingPanel](http://launchpad.net/wingpanel) has gone.

Is there any way to get it back?

Answer (score 1):

If you have, by any chance, tried to install [Synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project) / [indicator-search](https://code.launchpad.net/~elementary-apps/synapse-project/indicator-search) then this could be the reason as some versions are known to break WingPanel.

You should be able to uninstall it by typing (in Terminal):

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-synapse
```

Restart and check if it has any effect.

If yes and you added a PPA just for this, you should also [remove the PPA](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-do-i-remove-a-ppa).