# Remove corrupted repository

Tags: updates, software-installation, system, ppa, thirdpartyapps

[image]

How do I remove that manuelscheider repository??

Comment: You should be able to locate this repo in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and remove it with `sudo rm name-of-the-repo-file`

Comment: This may interest you: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-do-i-remove-a-ppa

Answer (score 1):

to delete a uncompatile or bad repository try this command in the termnial

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

when nano is openned, remove that bad repository (manuelscheider) and press

Ctrl + O to save and Ctrl + X to exit.

After this operation run this command in the terminal

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

And that is all. I hope help you